# Split float between list of numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem with splitting 0.00xxx float values between numbers.
Here is example of input [data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d03a0)
0 is sum of 1-3 float numbers.
As result I want to see rounded numbers without loosing sum of 1-3:

IN:

```
0 313.726
1 216.412
2 48.659
3 48.655
```

---

OUT:

```
0 313.73
1 216.41
2 48.66
3 48.66
```

How it should work:
Idea is to split the lowest rest(in our example it's 0.002 from value 216.412) between highest. 0.001 to 48.659 = 48.66 and 0.001 to 48.655 = 48.656 after this we can round numbers without loosing data.

---

After sitting on this problem yesterday I found the solution. The query as I think should look like this.

```
 select test.*, 
 sum(value - trunc(value, 2)) over (partition by case when id = 0 then 0 else 1 end) part, 
 row_number() over(partition by case when id = 0 then 0 else 1 end order by value - trunc(value, 2) desc) rn,
 case when row_number() over(partition by case when id = 0 then 0 else 1 end order by value - trunc(value, 2) desc) / 100 <= 
 round(sum(value - trunc(value, 2)) over (partition by case when id = 0 then 0 else 1 end), 2) then trunc(value, 2) + 0.01 else trunc(value, 2) end result
 from test;
```

But still for me it's strange to add const value "0.01" while getting the result.

---

**Any ideas to improve this query?**

Comment: Can you post for us an example of the result you would like to see ?

Comment: @Kibadachi In "grey" area I posted needed result

Comment: @Dmitry +1 for this interesting question. Below the proposal how to formalize the question. If this is what you are looking for, please edit the question and the final correct answer can be found: There are N floating point numbers that should be rounded to numbers with a precision of two decimal places. The rounding function (called round2) may diverge from the standard rounding, because the following rules must be fulfilled:  1) **sum(round(x)) = round2(sum(x))**   2)  **abs(round2(x) – x) < 0.01**   3) **sum(abs(round(x) – round2(x)))  is minimal**

Comment: With 1) and 2) I agree, but the lust one isn't correct. For numbers with low precision it can be max, for other one it should be minimal. It depends on count of values and precidion. And first one I think should look like round(sum(x)) = sum(round2(x))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pragamtic solution based on following rules:

1) check the difference between the rounded sum and sum of rounded parts.

```
 select round(sum(value),2) - sum(round(value,2)) from test where id != 0;
```

2) apply this difference

e.g. if you get 0.01, this means *one* rounded part must be *increased by 0.01*

if you get -.02, it means *two* rounded parts must be *decreased by 0.01*

The query below simple correct the last N parts:

```
with diff as (
select round(sum(value),2) - sum(round(value,2)) diff from test where id != 0
), diff_values as
(select sign(diff)*.01 diff_value, abs(100*diff) corr_cnt
from diff)
select id, round(value,2)
  + case when row_number() over (order by id desc) <= corr_cnt then diff_value else 0 end result
from test, diff_values where id != 0
order by id;


        ID     RESULT
 ---------- ----------
         1     216,41 
         2      48,66 
         3      48,66
```

If the number of corrected records in much higher than two, check the data and the rounding precision.

Comment: I think order should be like "case when row_number() over (order by value - trunc(value, 2))"

Comment: Your awesome. Testing.

Comment: Bad happens when I get negative value. For example with data:1 - 216,416; 2 - 48,653; 3 - 48,655

Comment: Maybe it's a bad idea to minus and add rest in same way?

Comment: @Dmitry if you want to assign the diference in oder of the "responsibility" for it, the order in row_number should be `order by sign(diff_value) * (value - round(value,2)) DESC`. Than it works also for you negative example.

Comment: Fail, but no. For example I wrote it doesn't work. But your ideas correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the round() sql function when presenting results. Round()'s second argument is the number of significant digits you want to round the number to. Issuing this select on the test table:

```
select id, round(value, 2) from test;
```

gives you the following result

```
0   313.73
1   216.41
2   48.66
3   48.65
```

Generally, you can use the stored numbers for summations and then use the round() function for presentation of the results:  Here is a way to do the sum with the full significant digits and then use the round() function for presenting the final result:

```
select sum(value) from test where id != 0
```

gives the result: 313.726

```
select round(sum(value), 2) from test where id != 0
```

gives the result: 313.73

By the way allow me two observations:

1) the rounding you give for id = 3 is confusing to me: 48.654 rounds to 48.65 rather than 48.66 in two significant digits. Am I missing something?

2) Strictly speaking this issue is not a pl/sql issue as labeled. It is totally in the realm of sql.  However there is a round() function in pl/sql as well and the same principles apply.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correct, you **don't** want to use round because rounding the partial numbers don't match the rounded total.

In this case simple trick is applied. You use round for all but the last number. The last fraction is calculated as a difference between the rounded sum and the rounded parts so far (all but the last one).

You may express this with analytical function as follows

```
 WITH total AS
   (SELECT id, value, ROUND(value,2) value_rounded FROM test WHERE id = 0
   ),
   rounded AS
   ( SELECT id, value, ROUND(value,2) value_rounded FROM test WHERE id != 0
   )
 SELECT id, value_rounded FROM total
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id,
   CASE
     WHEN row_number() over (order by id) != COUNT(*) over ()
     THEN
       /* not the last row - regular result */
       value_rounded
     ELSE
       /* last row - corrected result */
       (select value_rounded from total) - SUM(value_rounded) over (order by id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
   END AS value
 FROM rounded
 ORDER BY id;
```

Note that this is the test for the last numer

```
 row_number() over (order by id) != COUNT(*) over ()
```

and this is the sum of all parts from begin (UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) up to the one but last ( 1 PRECEDING)

```
  SUM(value_rounded) over (order by id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
```

I splitted your data in two source **total** - one row with the total and and **rounded** parts.

**UPDATE**

In some case the last corrected number shows an "ugly" large difference to the original value, 
as the differences in one rounding direction are higher that in the opposite one.

The following select takes this in account and distributes the difference between the parts.

The example bellow illustrated this on teh example with lot of 0.05s

```
 WITH nums AS
   (SELECT  rownum id, 0.005 value  FROM dual  connect by level <= 5   
   ),
   rounded AS
   ( SELECT id, value, ROUND(value,2) value_rounded FROM nums
   ),
   with_diff as 
   (SELECT id, value, value_rounded,
   -- difference so far - between the exact SUM and SUM of rounded parts
   -- cut to two decimal points
   floor(100* (
   sum(value) over (order by id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) -
   sum(value_rounded) over (order by id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)))
   / 100  diff_so_far
   FROM rounded),
   delta_diff as 
   (select id, value, value_rounded,DIFF_SO_FAR, 
     DIFF_SO_FAR - LAG(DIFF_SO_FAR,1,0) over (order by ID) as diff_delta
   from with_diff)
 SELECT id, value,  
   CASE
     WHEN row_number() over (order by id) != COUNT(*) over ()
     THEN
       /* not the last row - take the rounded value and ... */
       value_rounded +
       /* ... add or subtract the delta difference */
       diff_delta           
     ELSE
       /* last row - corrected result */
       round(sum(value) over(),2) - SUM(value_rounded + diff_delta) over (order by id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
   END AS value_rounded, diff_delta
 FROM delta_diff
 ORDER BY id;


         ID      VALUE VALUE_ROUNDED DIFF_DELTA
 ---------- ---------- ------------- ----------
          1       ,005             0      -0,01 
          2       ,005           ,01          0 
          3       ,005             0      -0,01 
          4       ,005           ,01          0 
          5       ,005           ,01      -0,01
```

Comment: The main problem is that the last number can contain the lowest rest so proportion can be violated

Comment: @Dimitry I added an update to address this problem. Anyway if you see a difference higher than say 0.02 between rounded SUM and SUM of rounded parts, I'd argue that the rounding precision should be increased. E.g. if all the values are in the interval from 0.05 to 0.01 the lowest rounding precision should be 3.

Comment: Very nice...Need to test :)

Comment: Have problems with rounding when values are 1 - 216,418; 2 - 48,659; 3 - 48,659

Comment: @Dmitry see my new "pragmatic" answer and consider the previous solutions as "trial" only. This is the way I'd approch the problem and I thing it is much clearer **how** the data are rounded.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, value, 
       case when id <> max(id) over () then round(value, 2) 
            else round(value, 2) - sum(round(value, 2)) over () +
                 round(first_value(value) over (order by id), 2) * 2 
       end val_rnd
  from test
```

Output:

```
    ID      VALUE    VAL_RND
------ ---------- ----------
     0    313.726     313.73 
     1    216.413     216.41 
     2     48.659      48.66 
     3     48.654      48.66
```

Above query works, but it moves all difference to last row. And this is not "honest" and maybe not what you are after for other scenarios. 
The most "unhonest" behavior is observable with big number of values, all equal `0.005`.

To make full distribution you need to:

- sum all original values in sub-rows and subtract rounded total value from row with id 0,
- use row_number() to sort sub-rows in order of difference between rounded value and original value (maybe descending, it depends on sign of difference, use `sign()`, `abs`),
- assign to each row value increased by .01 (or decreased if difference < 0 ) until it reaches difference/.01 (use `case when` ),
- union row with id = 0 containing rounded sum
- optionally sort results.

It's hard (but achievable) in one query. Alternative is some PL/SQL procedure or function, which might be more readable.

Comment: Yeap with pl it can be easy, but I have lots of data in table to analize and with pl it would be very slow